# SQL order minimum Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query the products not ordered since 01/01/2017 in SSMS.
So far I've come up with a couple of select count queries but have come up empty trying to figure this out. This has 3 tables attached to the query and I need the product names and IDs attached to the query result.

products table columns:
[product_id], [product_name], [brand_id], [category_id], [model_year], [list_price]

orders table columns:
[order_id], [item_id], [product_id], [quantity], [list_price], [discount]

order_items table columns:
[order_id], [customer_id], [order_status], [order_date], [required_date], [shipped_date],[store_id], [staff_id]

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM production.products
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sales.orders
                    JOIN sales.order_items oi ON orders.order_id = oi.order_id
                  WHERE orders.order_id = oi.order_id
                    AND orders.order_date > '2017-01-01');
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be useful, have a read of [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Find all the products that have been ordered since 01/01/2017, then query for products NOT in that list.

Comment: please show us the query that you have tried. thanks.

Comment: SELECT COUNT (*) FROM production.products
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sales.orders
JOIN sales.order_items oi ON orders.order_id = oi.order_id
WHERE orders.order_id = oi.order_id AND orders.order_date > '2017-01-01');

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is typically used together with a _correlated subquery_, i.e. a subquery having a condition referencing its outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into three parts

1. Order items and orders joined in the date range
2. Products not in #1

   ```
   WITH prodcuts_in_date_range as
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT oi.Product_id 
   FROM Order_items oi INNER JOIN Orders o on o.Order_id = oi.Order_id
   WHERE oi.Order_date > '2017-01-01')
   )
   SELECT * FROM Products p where p.Product_Id not in (SELECT Product_id from 
   products_in_date_range)
   ```